# Can Cassandra cluster have even number of nodes?

Tags: cassandra

Currently running a 3 node cluster with replication factor 3 on the keyspaces. Need to add more nodes to the cluster as the size of each node is approaching 2TB.
Can I add just 1 more node to the cluster and have a 4 node cluster or **does the cluster always need to have odd number of nodes?** Using a consistency level of ONE currently for both read and write.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have even number of nodes in a Cassandra cluster. So you can add another node to the cluster. If you are using vnodes, then it will be easier, otherwise a lot of work needs to be done to balance the cluster.
One more thing, reading and writing with consistency level `ONE` decreases the consistency. If it suits your usecase then it is fine but general recommendation is to use `QUORUM` on the production system.

Comment: The argument I'd counter with here, is that Cassandra is an AP eventually-consistent database, and utilizing lower consistency works with that intended design.  I actually recommend dev teams start with (LOCAL) ONE, and go to (LOCAL) QUORUM only if they notice consistency issues.

Comment: Sure noted Aaron. Thanks for updating.

Comment: Thanks for your responses Manish  and Aaron

Answer (score 8):

You can have as many nodes in the cluster as you want, particularly if you are not using the racks feature in Cassandra (all nodes are in the same logical C* rack).

If you are using C* racks, our recommendation is to have an equal number of nodes in each rack so the load distribution is balanced across the racks in each DC.

For example, if your app keyspaces have a replication factor of 3 and you have 3 racks then the number of nodes in the DC should be in multiples of the replication factor -- 3, 6, 9, 12 and so on. This would allow you to configure the same number of nodes in each rack.

This isn't a hard requirement but is best practice so nodes have an equal amount of load and data on them. Cheers!

Comment: Totally agree.  You'll get the best data distribution by going with a number of nodes that are a factor of your RF.

Comment: Thanks for your responses

Comment: So I could have any number of cassandra nodes if I am using a single rack with replication factor of 3?

Comment: Yes, @Cppcrusaders. 